# Rewriting system as a set of first order equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

What I'm given:
$$x'' = x' + y' + x + y$$
$$y'' = 2x' + 3y' + 3x + y$$
$$z=x'$$
$$w=y'$$

My solution: We know that $z'=x''$ and $w'=y''$. We can write:

$$z'=z+w+x+y$$
$$w'=2z+3w+3x+y$$

I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to do with the $x$ and $y$ still stuck in the derived first order equations, since I'm given $z=x'$, $w=y'$, and I'm only supposed to get a total of four first-order equations (so I can't define, for example, $z_0=∫zdx=x$). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Moo Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to do that. I was given specifically $z=x'$ and $w=y'$.

Comment: But you already have four first-order equations: $x'=z$, $y'=w$, $z'=z+w+x+y$, and $w'=2z+3w+3x+y$. What's the problem?

Comment: Are you still here? Anything to say about the comment or the answer?

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

$ \left(\begin{matrix}
x' \\
y' \\
z' \\
w' \\
\end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
w \\
\end{matrix}\right)$

See an example of solving in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equation_systems 
in section "Example (homogeneous)".